# Spring boot 3, WebSocket, Close connection

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I'm using spring boot 3 with `spring-boot-starter-websocket`. Can't figure out how to close connection by server's own will. Found that can get `SimpSession` from `SimpUserRegistry`.
But how to close it?